# Como acessar o dado em json e guardar em uma variável no python? flask-api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask

Eu estou fazendo um Flask Api muito simples, vou receber um title e um body em json..

```
{
"title":"Test",
"body":"test"
}
```

Minha classe app.py esta assim

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/item', methods=['POST'])
def addItem():
    data = request.get_json()
    return jsonify(data)
```

E eu tenho outra classe que tem um método que recebe um title e um body `item(title, body)`. Então gostaria de saber como transformo esse json e pego esses 2 parâmetros para poder chamar esse método.

**OBS: Eu não estou usando um banco de dados, esse programa é apenas para obter o json e chamar o método.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `get_json()` já trata o json e retorna pra você o objeto convertido em python:

```
data = request.get_json()
```

Aqui `data` já é um dicionário python, `data['title']` e `data['body']` possuem os dados que vieram no *request*.

Assim você pode chamar um método que receba os parâmetros corretos `def item(title, body)`, diretamente passando cada parâmetro:

```
item(**data)
```